# How can convert array of objects key value into the index value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a array of objects in a format of

```
 var val = [
  {
    posi: 6,
  },
  {
    posi: 4.5,
  },
  {
    posi: 2,
  },
  {
    posi: 7.5,
  },
  {
    posi: 2,
  },
  {
    posi: 5,
  },
  {
    posi: 3.5,
  },
];
```

and i want to change the key(posi) value into the position of the object in array, but if any key value as (.5) , i need to add the value into before index and need to continue the position for  above data into as
desired output as below

```
 var val = [
  {
    level: 1,
  },
  {
    level: 1.5,
  },
  {
    level: 2,
  },
  {
    level: 2.5,
  },
  {
    level: 3,
  },
  {
    level: 4,
  },
  {
    level: 4.5,
  },
];
```

and this is the code wrtitten to get desired output

```
 val = val.map((le, po) => {
  return {
    level: po + 1 - (le.level % 1 === 0.5 ? 0.5 : 0),
  };
});


OUTPUT :- [{"level":1},{"level":1.5},{"level":3},{"level":3.5},{"level":5},{"level":6},{"level":6.5}]
```

but its not working as required.

Please help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens to values 6 and 7.5? It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to keep track of the last key, so you can add to it the next iteration:

```js
const val=[{posi:6,},{posi:4.5,},{posi:2,},{posi:7.5,},{posi:2,},{posi:5,},{posi:3.5,},];

const result = [];

let key = 0;

for (const obj of val) {
    if (obj.posi % 1 !== 0) key += 0.5;
    else key = Math.floor(key + 1);
    
    result.push({ key });
}

console.log(result);
```

If `obj.posi` is not an integer (using `% 1` to test), then we just add `0.5` to the key. If it is an integer, we just add 1, but we make sure to floor the result since if `key` is not an integer, we'll incorrectly get another key that is not an integer (i.e., if `key` is 2.5 and we need an integer key, we should get floor(2.5 + 1) = 3).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `for` loop that keeps track of the previous level.

```js
let arr=[{posi:6},{posi:4.5},{posi:2},{posi:7.5},{posi:2},{posi:5},{posi:3.5},];
let res = [], prev = 0;
for (const {posi} of arr) {
  const level = prev + (posi % 1 === 0 ? 1 : .5);
  res.push({level});
  prev = Math.floor(level);
}
console.log(res);
```